# Create uri in nginx for a ghost blog

Tags: node.js, nginx, ghost-blog

I am trying to set up a ghost blog and want to use nginx to handle incoming requests. The ghost blog should be reachable by an url within a sub uri like: http://mydomain.com/blog articles would have urls like http://mydomain.com/blog/article1

So far my attempts to configure such a setup have not worked and I always get a 404 error. This is my config.js:

```
var path = require('path'),
    config;

config = {
    // ### Production
    // When running Ghost in the wild, use the production environment
    // Configure your URL and mail settings here
    production: {
        url: 'http://mydomain.com/blog',
        mail: {},
        database: {
            client: 'sqlite3',
            connection: {
                filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost.db')
            },
            debug: false
        },
        server: {
            // Host to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            // Port to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`, for iisnode set this to `process.env.PORT`
            port: '2368'
        }
    }
}
// Export config
module.exports = config;
```

And this is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain-com.log;

    location /blog {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This `location` works to access the blog with a path:

```
location ~^/blog(?<tail>.+$) {
   # more proxy stuff
   proxy_pass http://localhost:2368$tail;
}
```

Its performance is another matter.

But as you probably read in Ghost `config.js`:

> The url to use when providing links to the site, E.g. in RSS and email.
>   must not contain a path suffix after the hostname - "subdirs" are not (yet) supported!

In my tests, the blog home page works fine with `/blog`, but it contains the wrong links to the articles, without the leading `/blog`. But, if you navigate to an article and then edit its URL on the location bar inserting `/blog` it works too.

So I guess you'll need to hack a bit on Ghost or wait a little for next version.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use sub-domain to do this. and you do not need to change any config about Ghost.

```
upstream frontends {
    ip_hash;
    server 127.0.0.1:2368;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  blog.mydomain.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://frontends;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mydomain.com;

    location / {
    root   html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Support for subdirectories has only been implemented in version 0.4 of Ghost, if you were trying it with a version before, it probably didn't work, at least it should be much easier now, you can just do 1 to 1 proxying of the urls to your backend server.